# http request with Volley-api on Android

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I'm trying to make a http-post request to my localhost server. The problem I have Is that I'm not getting any response when I make the request.

I'm doing the request from a fragment class:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, " Button clickde");
                fLogin.setCallback(loginButton); //Let's register a callback

               final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", "AbCdEfGh123456");

                String url = "http://127.0.0.1/create_row.php";
                JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    }


                });

                fLogin.setFacebookListener(new FacebookLogin.OnFacebookListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookLoggedIn(JSONObject parameters) {

                    }
                });
            }

            });
```

Nothing is printed out from the `onResponse` or `Response.ErrorListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did't add the `jsObjRequest` to the queue, so the request wasn't executed, add it to the queue by:

```
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

see the tutorial on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html).